# Downgrading Spring security to AES-128

Tags: spring-security

I have a Spring framework based app in which I have been instructed to add AES-256 encryption. I have added this using the standard Spring security `Encryptors.textEncryptor(...)`

When I ran it on our development servers I got errors which indicated issues with key lengths so I updated the server's Java with Java JCE's unlimited policy files from Oracle.

However when attempting to get the code deployed to our test servers, the server admins are refusing to update the Java installations.

After talking with security, they suggested down grading the encryption from AES-256 to AES-128 under the assumption that it will work without the unlimited policy files.

As you can tell I'm not greatly knowledgeable in this area.

I've looked online, but it appears that the Spring encryption cannot be downgraded to AES-128.

Does anyone know if this downgrade can be done? or am I have to roll my own encryption setup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ended up using the spring source code as a base for rolling our own. Not hard really.

Comment: did you end up using public static BytesKeyGenerator shared(int keyLength)...I am needing to do same, and by far all I can see is using the ...shared(128) for key length could do the trick. I am curious about how did you achieve this. Not sure what I am missing but from your answer it also seems as if you had to change a lot in spring srouce but would that not break other existing things in the my codebase?

Comment: Sorry @Nirmal, the code was for a client and I don't have a copy. I probably (there's been a few projects since) looked at the spring source and used the class that implements the 256 encryption as a base for a 128 version. Making only what changes I needed. I think I only needed some very simple changes.